# How do to filter an Ext.data.Store returning any match on the record instance?

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am trying to filter a store based on a set of mapped Ext.util.Filters. For example:

```
comboBox.store.filter(_.map(this.displayFields, function (displayField) {
  return {
    property: displayField.name,
    value: queryString,
    anyMatch: true
  };
}));
```

this.displayFields is a list of display fields in my combobox template. In my combobox template I have something like:

```
'{codeValue} {displayValue} {descriptionValue}'
```

displayValue is the displayField property on my combobox. When I search for 'co' in my combobox, all displayFields must have 'co' in the value when I apply the filters to the store. My filters look like this:

```
[
  {property: 'codeValue', value: 'co'},
  {property: 'displayValue', value: 'co'},
  {property: 'desciptionValue', value: 'co'}
]
```

I would like a set of records that have the value 'co' in any of the displayFields' property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each filter is applied after the previous one, resulting in a logical "and". You've probably got that, or you wouldn't be asking. So, how do you get an "or" with Ext? If that were an "or" on values, you could use a regex for `value`, but you want it on `property`. As far as I know there isn't a built-in config option for that, but you can do anything you want in [`filterFn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter-cfg-filterFn).

Here's, for example, a combo that displays all records with an 'a', either in their code or name, and only them:

```
Ext.widget('combo', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    ,store: {
        fields: ['id', 'code', 'name']
        ,data: [
            {id: 1, code: 'a', name: 'Foo'}
            ,{id: 2, code: 'b', name: 'Bar'}
            ,{id: 3, code: 'ba', name: 'Baz'}
            ,{id: 4, code: 'z', name: 'Zoo'}
        ]
        ,filters: [{
            filterFn: function(record) {
                var match = false;
                Ext.each(fields, function(field) {
                    if (re.test(record.get(field))) {
                        match = true;
                        return false; // break the loop
                    }
                });
                return match;
            }
        }]
    }
    ,displayField: 'name'
    ,valueField: 'id'
});
```

Comment: I'll git it a try. Thank you for the response.